# removing space between blocks

Tags: html, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I make some block with image and i want put their in one line inside each other and have some space between them .
I expect this to be **horizontal** and less inner space.
I want to removing space between blocks.

```css
 /* remove spacing between middle columns */
  .row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:not(:first-child):not(:last-child) {
    padding-right:0;
    padding-left:0;
  }
  /* remove right padding from first column */
  .row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:first-child {
    padding-right:0;
  }
  /* remove left padding from first column */
  .row.no-gutter [class*='col-']:last-child {
    padding-left:0;
  }


  /* only for column content visible */
  .col-md-1>div {background-color:#ddd;}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row no-gutter" >
        <div class="col-md-6"   style="background-color:#d9eaf2;color: #6666ccff;font-family: Roboto,Tahoma,Helvetica,sans-serif;font-size: 14px;margin-bottom: 6px;">i expect this to be horizontal and less inner space.placing it above head in wordpress theme just after head
    </div>
  <div class="col-md-1 align-middle"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2940" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="col-md-1 align-middle"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2947" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2946" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2945" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2944" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
<div class="col-md-1"><img class="aligncenter size-full wp-image-2942" src="https://cdn0.iconfinder.com/data/icons/Social_Network_Icons_gloss/350/Facebook-px.png" alt="" width="28" height="28" /></div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that I understood your problem, but maybe you just need to wrap your divs with the facebook logo in an another div, and add a `display:flex;`

Check this example and let me know if it answer your question :)

https://codepen.io/mdubus/pen/NeQOKe

Comment: Okay then just add a `   display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;` to the div you added :)

Comment: great it works fine but creates equal space combined to left check site above

Comment: I don't understand what you try to achieve. Could you maybe post an image of the result you attend ? Then I would be more able to help you

Comment: kindly check image at http://prntscr.com/m9lcrj and inspect  jaipur.onlinewebshop.net

Comment: So you want to remove the left space, and align your logo facebook to the left of your block ? If so change the `justify-content: flex-end;` to `justify-content: start;`

And don't forget to add `class="col-md-6"` to your div ;)

if that's not the problem, please explain in detail what you want to achieve :)

Comment: please let me know have you seen site above  jaipur.onlinewebshop.net aligning left will create space to right and right to left

Comment: Yes I have seen your website, but don't understand what you want.
Do you want to center the block with the facebook logo ?

Comment: Ok then just remove the `class="col-md-6" from your left div, and it should do the trick :)

Comment: What's wrong with your icons ? what do you want to achieve ? Same as below, if you want help please provide a screenshot of want you want to do. Else please mark the response below as resolved :) Thanks !

Comment: finally got it striped off col-md1 along with 6 and added margin-left: 22em for icons.perfectly done.